# Using cvxopt for mean square error

Tags: python, cvxopt, mean-square-error

I want to get the θ estimates that minimize the mean square error, using the cvxopt package of python. After a bit of digging I found a useful [link](http://maggotroot.blogspot.gr/2013/11/constrained-linear-least-squares-in.html) that helped me understand how the package works. But I cannot link my equation with the form that the package needs.

What I have: 
min ||y - θ.T*X||^2 
and I want to bring it to a form : 
θ.Τ * Q * θ + r * θ 
* where θ.Τ is the transposed vector of θ, and y, X are the vectors of the linear regression (y=θ.Τ*Χ+n).

Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is more about programming and not math?

Comment: I don't see those two form relating to each other. Usually, x is the variable-vec to optimize while theta(?) describes the data-input. This assumption is note compatible the the quadratic-form (which looks somewhat different; see wiki or cvxopt's standard-form; usually 0.5 x.T Q x + c.T x). The task itself does not sound hard (hint: only diagonals of Q will be nonzero; value depends on the 0.5 factor), but the descriptions may be somewhat misleading. Also maybe more important: any reason not to use cvxpy? (it would basically do all this for you and can use cvxopt's solvers or many others)

Comment: @Sascha: didn't know about cvxpy, from a quick look it seems "simpler" to handle than cvxopt... I will look it up more, thanks. Also in my case X, y are the inputs and I am searching the best theta parameter for the model's estimation.